# print vs. echo in R

Tags: r, echo, batch-processing, rscript

I'm running a batch process using Rscript. I would like to print messages to screen just like "echo" does in bash.  So I use the function "print".

The problem is that print's output does not go to the screen. It goes to the log file instead. Anybody knows what's the equivalent of echo in R?

Comment: Note: cat also goes to the log file.

Comment: Try `cat` or `message`.

Comment: Thanks.  cat doesn't work. But message does it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Thomas pointed out on the comments...

`message ("Print this on the screen")`

For more info you can check the [message documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/message.html)